# D3 - using enter() and exit() selections to update child elements

Tags: d3.js

I have g.row elements containing g.cell elements, each containing a rect element. My nested data is bound to g.row and then g.cell. The rect elements access the data bound to g.cell.

At the moment my enter and exit selections add and remove g.cell. It would be more efficient to have them add and remove the rect elements, because g.cell has events bound to it that I need to reassign. But is this possible? I can't see how to get it to work.

I've managed to run `cell.exit().selectAll("rect").remove();` which works fine. But `cell.enter().selectAll("g.cell").append("rect");` throws an error ("[this code] is not a function"). While `cell.enter().append("rect")` doesn't append a rect.

Current code on g.cell:

```
  var cell = row.selectAll("g.cell")
    .data(function(d){
      return d.value.filter(function(p){
        if (p[1]=='') {
          return horizNodesCopy.indexOf(p[0])!=-1;
        } else {
          return horizNodesCopy.indexOf(p[0]+' -- '+p[1])!=-1;
        }
      });
    });


  var cell2 = cell.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class",function(d,i,j){ return "cell cell_"+i; })
      .attr('transform',function(d,i,j){
          if (d[1]=='') {
            return 'translate('+ x(d[0]) +',0)';
          } else {
            return 'translate('+ x(d[0]+' -- '+d[1]) +',0)';
          }

    });

    addRectangles(cell2,colorScale);

    cell.exit().remove();
```

This feels like it's going to be something obvious :/